# Restoring systemd

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, systemd, crash, rescue-mode

I have **duale boot** windows and xubuntu on my pc.I mistakenly remove all **Systemd** directories and xubuntu crash in login page and the resolution of it becomes low and it does not boot. How can I restore systemd with all dependencies and configuration. Its better that my packages not be destroyed.

thanks

Comment: You've not provided any release details; but in your case I'd just restore from your backups, OR alternatively just do a non-destructive re-install of Xubuntu (*Xubuntu being a flavor is actually easier than Ubuntu Desktop in my experience; alas I'm stuck to be generic as you didn't provide release details - but it's likely what I'd do as it'll be faster I suspect than even restoring data from backups!*)

Comment: It mean that I should use a bootable flash for reinstalling xubuntu?

Comment: Can I improve it with rescue mode?

Comment: If you're using `grub` you can modify that to boot an ISO that exists on non-bootable media (ie. on a disk partition that isn't booted), but again I'm speaking *generically* as you've not provided any release details, but booting *flash* or USB media is usually the easiest way to re-install; with re-installs taking 2-3 minutes on fast hardware (*though non-destructive re-installs that also required loads of packages to download will take longer, as will using a slower machine with spinning rust type drives etc*)